# Connect server through switch on local network

Tags: networking, switch

What I am trying to do is to connect two computers together through switch.
First computer is with Win8 OS.
Other is Ubuntu Server 12.04 OS (apache webserver).

I am connecting them with LAN cable through the Switch.
Scheme is as follows:
Win8 Machine <-> Switch <-> Ubuntu Server

What I would expect is that I would be able to open Ubuntu WebServer from my Win8 machine by entering IP address 192.168.1.5 in my browser, or access server with putty. But it doesn't work. The Win8 machine do not see the ubuntu server machine.

I have tried to set a static IP address for a webserver instead of DHCP but that doesn't change anything.
What could be wrong here?

I am not very experienced user, so if someone have some ideas could you please describe the possible solution in a simple if possible step by step way. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are the IP's you are using? What is the switch? Is the webserver service started?

Comment: @canadmos The IP's are: 192.168.1.3 on Win8 machine and 192.168.1.5 on Ubuntu server machine. The webserver service is started. And the switch is a basic 8 port 100Mbps Ethernet Switch (I do not know the brand).

Comment: Are you able to ping 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.3 and ping 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.5 ?

Comment: @user2196728 No, the ping on Win8 returns that `Destination host unreachable`. and the ping on linux returns: `Network is unreachable`. Also tested the Switch itself, it is working.

Comment: How did you test the switch itself to tell it is working ? also, are you able to ping 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.5 ?

Comment: @user2196728 Yes I am able to ping 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.3 (and the same with 192.168.1.5). The switch is most likely working because for example if I connect switch to Internet (Internet router -> Switch -> Win8 PC) then Internet is working on Win8 PC (on any Switch ports), so I guess that the Switch should be ok, also the switch is new and never have been used.

Comment: And does `Internet router -> Switch -> Linux PC` works ? (mean, do you have Internet access from your Linux in this configuration ?)

Comment: @user2196728 It is getting somewhere, apparentrly I do not have a connection to `Linux PC` in that way. I tried to run `ping www.google.com` on LInux and had error: `Network is unreachable`. But that is strange, I mean because the Linux Server did worked on other network when was connected the same way but with Router instead of Switch `Server -> Router -> Win8` and everything worked. Now, on basically the same network only with Switch, it doesnt work.

Comment: @user2196728 Many thanks for your quick responses. But I just cannot make it work, I have no idea why. Apparently the Linux machine is somehow mis-configured. I have decided to reinstall the Linux Server completely, in hope that this will resolve the issue.

Comment: hmm not sure you have to reinstall just for a network issue...do you have uplink on your ethernet port (mean some leds are flashing or not) ?

Comment: @user2196728 I have no idea what was wrong but yes after complete linux server reinstall everything works as it should. Thank you again for your time and help.